# Введите правильный операт

Tags: python

Введите правильный оператор, чтобы умножить 7 на 3, и распечатайте результат в Python: print(7__3) . Обязательно введите в поле ниже только оператора.

Comment: почитайте книжку

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Answer (score 2):

Оператором умножения в Python является знак "*":

```
print(7 * 3)
```

Comment: print(7*3) - не верно

Comment: Результат будет правильным, можете в этом сами убедиться. Впрочем, можете попробовать, следуя стандартам PEP 8, до и после оператора умножения поставить пробелы.

Comment: ну меня не пропускает дальше. говорит ошибка

Comment: с пробелами тоже не идет

Comment: @KotRyżow, скопируйте текст ошибки и напишите в тексте вопроса.

Comment: я выполняю тест с заданием   - дзе нету вариантов ответа

Comment: Enter the correct operator to multiply 7 by 3, and print the result in Python: print(7__3). Be sure to enter only the operator into the field below.